# C# Validating a password on SERVER SIDE

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

I'm right now trying to validate a password on the server side using .NET

Here's my client side code:

```
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PSWRD" runat="server" Width="120px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <span style="background-color:yellow; color:red; font-weight:bold;" title="some rules">Password Rules</span>

                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="VPSWRD" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="A password is required"
                        ControlToValidate="PSWRD">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="IPSWRDVal" runat="server"
                        OnServerValidate="ValidatePasswordServerSide"
                        ControlToValidate="PSWRD"
                        ErrorMessage="Please enter a *valid* password"
                        ValidateEmptyText="False"
                        ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

My first validator works fine. It displays it's message when appropriate.

The second one gives me trouble.

Here's my code behind

```
protected void ValidatePasswordServerSide(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{


        if (Regex.IsMatch(args.Value, @"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$"))
            args.IsValid = true;
        else
            args.IsValid = false;


}
```

The issue is that I'm not seeing an error message display for my second validator whenever I enter an incorrect value.

Also a little plea, before people get too exotic with their solutions please note this for a school assignment, so they want a cookie cutter approach. I know, it's dumb but rules are rules.

Comment: There's really no need to include the phrase "ServierSide" in your method names.  The code is by definition on the server side.

Comment: Have you debugged at the `Regex.IsMatch` to see whether the function is called or not and if it is, whether the Regular Expression results in a match or not.

Comment: I see now. I tried debugging it before, but I have other fields in my page with validators. I left them blank thus their validators would trip false first and my server side code would never execute. I feel silly, now.

Comment: All validators have an `Enabled` (boolean) setting.  You can set all others to "False" to stop them interrupting the debug.  Just remember to remove/set to "True" afterward.

Answer (score 0):

it is bad think for call server side method for check password validate.

Use

```
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="rgpassvalide"  ErrorMessage="Please enter a *valid* password"  ControlToValidate="PSWRD" ValidationExpression="^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

insted of  "asp:CustomValidator".

above code helps you to make it working.